# Which field will be used to name the home folder?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, office365, azure-activedirectory

We've got Office365 and AzureAD. 
One user is having some issues with his home folder.
Name: John Döe
Account: john.doe@mycompany.com

User signs in with his office365 account - john.doe@mycompany.com
First time he signs in to the device it creates a home folder C:\Users\johndöe

With some application and repositories that require to work from within his home folder they have issues with encoding the folder name.

If I wish to ensure this doesn't happen in the future for more people. Where can I change the name of the user to ensure that the home folder is created without any special characters but still display his information correctly?

As in:
C:\Users\johndoe - john.doe@mycompany.com - Display name: John Döe
c:\Users\janedoe - jane.doe@mycompany.com - Display name: Jane Döe

Thanks in advance.

EDIT for some clarification: 
Office365 portal I can change "First name, Surname and Display name".

Should I change
First name: John
Surname: Döe
Display name: John Doe

Or: 
First name: John
Surname: Doe
Display name: John Döe

Comment: wouldn't you just use a standard character when the account is created? and have the display name have the special character as you've already depicted? if you change the name afterword, the original name is likely still going to be cached on the computer unless you reprofile them completely

Comment: @mael' I will wipe the device and let the user sign in from scratch again. So change Surname to Doe and have display name as Döe?

Comment: Does Azure AD have any equivalent to traditional AD "sAMAccountName"?

Comment: that should do it, yes - it's going to cause issues sending mail to that address anyway if it has a special character and you're operating in an environment where that character is not common - so at the very least you want to add an alias with the standard/special character (whatever isn't used in the account name).

Comment: @mael' I had to change Display Name, first name and surname fields did nothing. The only required field for users in office365 admin panel is the display name. Feels odd to have such hard coupling within the office and azure platform.

Comment: wow yeah that’s pretty stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have hoped to find a better solution to this. but this is how I did it.

Changed my display name in office365 admin panel to **John Doe** instead of **John Döe**.
Created a fresh install of Windows and logged in as john.doe@mycompany.com which now created homefolder *C:\Users\JohnDoe* instead of *C:\Users\JohnDöe*.

After user is setup on the machine, I changed the Display Name back in Office 365 admin panel to **John Döe** to ensure everything is shown properly.

Been using this now since I posted this question and haven't had any issues.